# Choose column name dynamically in namedParameterJdbcTemplate in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-jdbc

Hi The question is pretty straight forward

We all know this query works

```
String query = SELECT * FROM DATABASE_LOCKER WHERE LAST_HOUR = :last_hour

        MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        parameters.addValue("last_hour","2");


getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().update(
                    QueryConstants.query, parameters);
```

But is this possible in any way?? That is I need to give the column name of a table dynamically

```
String query = SELECT * FROM DATABASE_LOCKER WHERE :last_hour = 1

    MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
    parameters.addValue("last_hour","LAST_HOUR");


getNamedParameterJdbcTemplate().update(
                QueryConstants.query, parameters);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use it like as below :

```
if(yourCondition){
columnName = "ABCD";
}else{
columnName = "A1B2C3";
}
```

In Code you can use the column name dynamically like :

```
   public/ private Object / void someDaoMethod(String columnName, String value){
    String query = "SELECT * FROM DATABASE_LOCKER WHERE "+columnName+"="+value";
    .....

    }
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your answer. But I'm maintaining the query Strings in a separate file and I would like to keep the query string in one piece. Any help wud be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you are using properties file, I could have suggested you like this...

```
queryToGetFromDabaseLocker = SELECT * FROM DATABASE_LOCKER WHERE {0} = {1}
```

In Code, you can simply use like :

Read property file value like this :

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
try {
  properties.load(new FileInputStream("path/filename"));
} catch (IOException e) {
  ...
}
```

Iterate as:

```
String query = "";
String formatteQuery = "";
    for(String key : properties.stringPropertyNames()) {
       if(key.equals("queryToGetFromDabaseLocker")){
      query = properties.getProperty(key);
      formatteQuery = MessageFormat.format(query , "YourColumnName", "YourValue");
       }
    }
```